# Efficient way to save last X amount of integers

Tags: java

I get all kinds of data, which gets updated every second. I need to write a function that gives me the last 30 values (of the last 30 seconds) of a certain attribute. What would be the most memory-efficient way to save the last 30 values of something? Everything older than 30 seconds can be discarded. I have to do this action 96k times/second.

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of those 30?

Comment: I should have clarified that, yes I do.

Comment: If you have attempted this already, post your code and describe any errors you encounter. If you have not attempted this already, try it and then ask a question in accordance with SO's guidelines on asking questions.

Comment: Last 30 values or all the values that came in the last 30 seconds? These are two very different problems with very different solutions.